# Why id gradient normal to the level set?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition

I'm new to multi-variable calculus (just completed single variable calculus). After watching Khan Academy's videos I was trying to understand why is a gradient normal to level sets (e.g. if we talk about a scalar function with two inputs (x,y)). I found a similar query but couldn't understand the best answer.

Would it be possible to elaborate on this answer geometrically (or with an example)? - https://mathoverflow.net/a/2049/477160

I've just joined the new community, so can't comment on the query. Hence, posting this as a question.

Comment: Do you know about directional derivatives?

Comment: Yes, basically we use gradient at point and dot product it with the unit vector in the desired direction. I do realize that gradient points to the direction of steepest ascent and hence, we can say that gradient would be perpendicular. However, I'm interested in the solution (in the link given). It would help me better understand intuitively as to why gradient has a direction even though it is just a derivative w.r.t to x & y (for a scalar function with 2 inputs).